# How to input entities translations using one form (Symfony using Gedmo\Translatable)

Tags: php, forms, translation, symfony4

I'm working on a multilingual website and want the users to be able to create Categories (and other entities) in many languages.

Here is a extract from my entity Category :

**PHP**

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;    

    // ... getters and setters ...

}
?>
```

Gedmo stores all the translations for all my entities in a table, with this structure :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id | locale | object_class | field | foreign_key | content |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where *object_class* refers to the Entity class (e.g. : App\Entity\Category) and *foreign_key* refers to the currently translated entity.

Actually, the translations are well displayed according to the current locale in the url, and the content adapts when the user changes the language.

The user is also able to add some categories, here is my CategoryType :

```
<?php
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Category name'
                ],
                'label' => 'Category name',
            ])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Category description',
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Category description',
                ]
            )

            ->add('send', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Send'
            ])
            ->add('image', FileType::class, [
                'label' => 'Illustration',
                "mapped" => false,
                "required" =>false,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Category::class,
        ]);
    }
}?>
```

The thing is : when a new category is added, the name and the description are only set for the current locale. When we want to update a category for a given locale, the user must go to the form, but using the locale for which he wants to modify the category.

This is functional but not really simple.

I tried [a2lix bundle](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle) but the last version isn't compatible with Gedmo anymore, and I would like to avoid creating an EntityTranslation with all the translatable fields for an Entity.

So, here is my question : is it possible to allow the user to input names and descriptions for different languages, using only one form ?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was in the same situation as you, but I used [DoctrineBehaviors bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors). I solved that problem using the [Symfony embedded forms](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/embedded.html) (version 2.5). The main idea of the solution is to manage two entities in the same form, where one entity will have the fields that do not need to be translated and the other will contain the fields that are needed translate. Then two forms must be created and one will contain the other, as the following code shows:

- **VideoType.php**:

  `use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackValidator;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
  use Sistema\FilmsBundle\Form\VideoTranslationType;

  class VideoType extends AbstractType{

      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
          $builder
              ->add('showreelTranslation', 'collection', array('type' => new VideoTranslationType()))
              ->add('contenido','textarea', array('required' => true,'max_length' => 1500))
              ->add('publico','choice',  array(
                      'choices' => array(
                              '1' => 'Si',
                              '0' => 'No',
                      ),
                      'required' => true,
                      'multiple'  => false,
                      'expanded'=>true
                  )
              )

          ;

      }       

      public function getName(){
          return 'sistema_adminbundle_videotype';
      }

  }`


  ?>
- **VideoTranslationType.php**:

  namespace Sistema\FilmsBundle\Form;

  use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

  class VideoTranslationType extends AbstractType
  {
      /**
       * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
       * @param array $options
       */
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
          $builder
              ->add('titulo','text', array('max_length' => 149,'required' => true))
              ->add('descripcion','text', array('max_length' => 199,'required' => true))
              ->add('publicar', 'submit')
          ;
      }

  ```
  /**
   * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
   */
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
          'data_class' => 'Sistema\FilmsBundle\Entity\ShowreelTranslation'
      ));
  }

  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getName()
  {
      return 'sistema_filmsbundle_videotranslation';
  }
  ```

  }

Also, I leave the source code of the controller and twig template.

[VideoController.php](https://pastebin.com/rH8FTJ9P)
[video.html.twig](https://pastebin.com/Gc4qwxEC)

PS: In [this link](http://kamiladryjanek.com/working-with-symfony-and-doctrine-entities-translations/) there is a guide how to use DoctrineBehaviors in case you need it

I hope I've helped :)

Comment: Hi Francisca, thank you for your anwser ! I finally used Prezent translations, which is compatible with the a2lix bundle I mentionned. With Prezent, you have to store all the translatable field in an other entity, but you're able to easily input all the translations ;)

Comment: In fact, I still have [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929994/how-to-display-a-message-in-the-default-locale-when-the-message-is-not-available) when the translation is not available for a locale, but the input process is now resolved with Prezent.